# single column stacked bar chart with label annotations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  name                value
  <chr>               <dbl>
1 age                -1.14 
2 daysInHospital      0.371
3 X...lymphocyte      0.469
4 neutrophils...      0.829
5 rfv_age            41    
6 rfv_daysInHospital  5    
7 rfv_X...lymphocyte  6.2  
8 rfv_neutrophils... 91
```

I want to plot a single column using `ggplot` where the `y-axis` is followed by the values for `age`, `daysInHospital`, `X...lymphocyte` and `neurphils`. Then the labels of the `geom_col` (or something similar) as the values which contain the `rfv_...`

I cannot seem to plot just the four observations I want. The following is not what I want.

```
d %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
   geom_col()
```

The expected output would be a stacked column with the values from the four mentioned and then the annotation coming from the numbers in the `value` column which correspond to the the variables which contain the characters `rfv`.

That is, the values for `age`, `daysInHospital`, `X...lymphocyte` and `neurphils` come from a model and the values which contain the `rfv`(raw feature value) are the actual values for that observation.

Data:

```
structure(list(name = c("age", "daysInHospital", "X...lymphocyte", 
"neutrophils...", "rfv_age", "rfv_daysInHospital", "rfv_X...lymphocyte", 
"rfv_neutrophils..."), value = c(-1.14369773864746, 0.371403247117996, 
0.46945133805275, 0.829460024833679, 41, 5, 6.2, 91)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `tidyr::extract` because your data is a bit of a mess.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
d %>%
  tidyr::extract(col = name, into = c("type","variable"),
                 regex = "(rfv)?_?(.*)") %>%
  mutate(type = replace_na(type,"value")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = variable, values_from = value, names_from = type) 
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  variable        value   rfv
  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>
1 age            -1.14   41  
2 daysInHospital  0.371   5  
3 X...lymphocyte  0.469   6.2
4 neutrophils...  0.829  91
```

Then we can plot the data with `geom_bar`:

```
d %>%
  tidyr::extract(col = name, into = c("type","variable"), regex = "(rfv)?_?(.*)") %>%
  mutate(type = replace_na(type,"value")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = variable, values_from = value, names_from = type) #%>%
ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(1), y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = rfv, x = 1.5), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  labs(x = "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ian Campbell - that you need to tidy your data first. This was my effort:

```r
d %>% 
 mutate(rfv = lead(value, 4)) %>% 
 filter(seq(nrow(.)) < 5) %>%  
 ggplot(aes(x = "Variable", y = value, fill = name)) + 
 geom_col(width =0.3) +
 geom_text(aes( label = rfv), position = "stack", vjust = 3)
```

[image]